# How to use PC Joystick from Raspberry PI via TeamViewer?

Tags: raspbian, python, joystick

I've installed TeamViewer 11 Host in my Raspberry PI 3 and I can access my Raspberry PI by using the TeamViewer. But the problem is that, I can't access my Joystick that is connected in my PC from Raspberry PI using the TeamViewer. Is there any way that I can access my PC Joystick from Raspberry PI via TeamViewer?

I've a python script that is working in my PC but not in Raspberry PI. I've installed `pygame` package in Raspberry PI.

```
import os
import pygame

pygame.init()
j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()

print('Initialized Joystick : %s' %j.get_name())
```

When I run the script in Raspberry PI, it gives error:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > File "TestJoystick.py", line 13, in
> >
> > j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
> >
> > pygame.error: Invalid joystick device number

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.